# How to use Procyon Decompiler with Diffoscope

Tags: java, diff, binary-reproducibility

I was running Diffoscope on Ubuntu Bionic and when I turned on the debug log (`--debug`) I noticed many lines like these (one per `.class` file in the `JAR`):

```
diffoscope.comparators.java: Unable to find ProcyonDecompiler. Falling back...
```

I installed the package `procyon-decompiler` but the errors persist. How can I make Diffoscope work with Procyon? I can't find any documentation about this integration!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the Python sources of `diffoscope`, I figured out that `diffoscope` was expecting an executable named `procyon-decompiler` in the path.

`/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/diffoscope/comparators/java.py:L40`:

```
@tool_required('procyon-decompiler')
def cmdline(self):
    return ['procyon-decompiler', '-ec', self.path]
```

In Ubuntu Bionic, the `procyon-decompiler` package installs Procyon as `procyon` and not `procyon-decompiler`. I made this work by creating a symbolic link. E.g.:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/procyon ~/.local/bin/procyon-decompiler
```

Comment: Under _Fedora Remix WSL_ I had this `'procyon' not available in path. Falling back to binary comparison.` I was able to solve it with a symbolic link as you said but the other way around: `ln -s /usr/bin/procyon-decompiler ~/.local/bin/procyon` I had to `mkdir ~/.local/bin` THANKS!